# Tab Control and Field Check on Form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, tabcontrol

MS ACCESS 2007
VBA CODE BUILDER

I am able to show a MsgBox in VBA code when a Tab is selected with

```
Private Sub TabCtl34_Change()
If Me.TabCtl34.Value = 1 Then 'First Page
MsgBox "Hi"
End If
End Sub
```

But I also want to check if the second tab is selected and a field(Name) on the form IS NULL (not on tab), msgbox or cancel event to require Name to be entered before they see the second tab.

When I add in:

```
Private Sub TabCtl34_Change()
If Me.TabCtl34.Value = 1 AND [FORMS]![FORMNAME]![NAME] IS NULL Then 
MsgBox "Hi"
End If
End Sub
```

It just goes directly to the second tab even if the name is null. How do i write the vba code so it can do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IS NULL` is for use in query expressions, from VBA use the `IsNull()` VBA function.

```
If Me.TabCtl34.Value = 1 AND IsNull([FORMS]![FORMNAME]![NAME]) Then
```

As you are running this from the form's module you can use `Me` to refer to the current form-instance:

```
If Me.TabCtl34.Value = 1 AND IsNull(Me.[NAME]) Then
```

You should also consider that the value may be an empty string, rather than NULL. You can combine both checks using:

```
If Me.TabCtl34.Value = 1 And Len(Me.[NAME].Value & "") = 0 Then
```

Concatenating the empty string "" coerces a NULL value to a string.

(It is preferable to explicitly identify the property `Value` rather than assume it as the default property.)